exec keyword on a background command?
Normally, in a bash script, exec replaces the bash process, and the rest of the script is ignored:
#!/bin/bash
exec command1
command2        # will not execute

However, if we add & after the exec line, it will continue to run:
#!/bin/bash
exec command1 &
command2        # will execute

It seems totally equivalent to a non-exec script which simply puts command1 to background:
#!/bin/bash
command1 &
command2        # will execute

Is it really no difference between using and not using exec on a background command?
Will it be faster or slower if using exec?

Just curious - since it wouldn't make sense to write exec command1 &, why do you care how fast it is?

If the behavior is totally the same, then I want to choose the faster one.

I answer you with a small example.
main.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Main PID = $BASHPID"
exec ./exec_background.sh &
exec ./exec.sh

exec.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Exec PID = $BASHPID"

exec_background.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Exec Background PID = $BASHPID"

Running it you get, for example:
Main PID = 9547
Exec PID = 9547
Exec Background PID = 9548

As you can see the exec command reports the same PID of the main bash instance, instead the background exec command spawns a new bash shell (by the different PID).
In conclusion, the background exec commmand behaves like a standard background execution command without the exec keyword.
I think that the execution time of the two variants is the same, both have to spawn a new bash shell.

A command line backgrounded with & is forked from the main process then executed. The command in this case is exec, but by the time that gets run, the backgrounding has already caused the fork to happen.
A foreground exec would get run by the same process that is handling the main thread of execution for the script.
Since the purpose of exec is to replace she shell with the named command, it stands to reason that a forked/backgrounded use would allow the main process to continue unencumbered.
